# using python finditer, how can I replace each matched string?

Tags: python, iterator, plpython

I am using Python (pl/python, actually) to find, successively, a series of regex matches in a very large text object. This is working fine! Each match is a different result, and each replace will be a different result, eventually based on a query inside the loop.

For the moment, I'd be happy to replace every match in rx with *any* text, just so I'd understand how it works. Can someone give me an explicit example of replacing the matched text?

*match.group(1)* seems to correctly indicate the matched text; is this the way to do things?

```
plan3 = plpy.prepare("SELECT field1,field2 FROM sometable WHERE indexfield = $1", 
  [ "text" ])

rx = re.finditer('LEFT[A-Z,a-z,:]+RIGHT)', data)

# above does find my n matches...

# -------------------  THE LOOP  ----------------------------------
for match in rx:
 # below does find the 6 match objects - good!

 # match.group does return the text
 plpy.notice("--  MATCH: ", match.group(1))

 # must pull out a substring as the 'key' to an SQL find (a separate problem)
 # (not sure how to split based on the colon:)
 keyfield = (match.group(1).split, ':')
 plpy.notice("---------: ",kefield)

try:
 rv = plpy.execute(plan3, [ keyfield ], 1 )

# ---  REPLACE match.group(1) with results of query
# at this point, would be happy to replace with ANY STRING to test...
except:
 plpy.error(traceback.format_exc())

# -------------------  ( END LOOP )  ------------------------------
```

Answer (score 10):

You want [`re.sub()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.sub) instead.

```
import re

def repl(var):
  return var.group().encode('rot13')

print re.sub('[aeiou]', repl, 'yesterday')
```

> yrstrrdny

Comment: Ignacio - OK, tks for this - I'm now trying re.sub(), with some success. But how do I substring search the match, to pull out a bit I need?

Comment: The function will be passed the [match object](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#match-objects)